# python: how to use checkbox label as var en input from csv-file?

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

> My code will not read the input from the checkboxlabel named text, i
>   want to use the input from text as a variable and do actions with it.
>
> I do not understand the  "var1.get()" function. Anyone know how yo get
>   the text valua if checkted out of the box and use it as var?
>
> I Googlen onvar.get() functie and youtube but no answers.

```
def create_widgets(self):
    signkeuze=[]        
    signfilecsv= appsign("pal.csv")
    signfilecsv.signalen(signkeuze)
    Label(self, text="select")
    self.comedy=BooleanVar()
    y=0
    x=0
    for x in range (1):
        for row in range (1):
            #print x
            self.comedyvar=signkeuze
            #print signkeuze
            Checkbutton(self, text=signkeuze[x], variable = self.comedy, command=self.update_text).grid(row=y, column=0, sticky=W)
            Checkbutton(self, text=signkeuze[x+1], variable = self.comedy, command=self.update_text).grid(row=row+1, column=0, sticky=W)
            Checkbutton(self, text=signkeuze[x+x], variable = self.comedy, command=self.update_text).grid(row=row+1, column=0, sticky=W)
```

Answer (score 0):

The var1.get() method returns the state of the checkbox, not the text associated with it. The text associated with the checkbox is constant and does not change when you click the checkbox.

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
text1 = "foo"
var1 = Tkinter.IntVar()
chk = Tkinter.Checkbutton(root, text=text1, variable=var1)
chk.pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT)


var1.get()  # returns 0 if unchecked and 1 if checked 
if var1.get():
    print text1
```

If you have several checkboxes and want to find out the text associated with all the ones that are checked, you can simply make a `list` of text and a `list` of IntVar. For example,

```
texts = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz']
vars = [Tkinter.IntVar(), Tkinter.IntVar(), Tkinter.IntVar()]

for j, var in enumerate(vars):
    chk = Tkinter.Checkbutton(root, text=texts[j], variable=var)
    chk.pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT)
...
for j, var in enumerate(vars):
    if var.get():
       print texts[j] # only prints the text corresponding to the variables that are checked.
```

Comment: what command of function do i use to get the text associated with the state? Or were do i begin with writing code for that? My solution wish is to check the boxvalue and use the text associated with it as a variable to open csv files of use the text in een for-loop etc.

Comment: checkboxes can also have strings for values. It almost sounds like the OP wants to get a string rather than a checked/unchecked value.

Comment: Thats right @Bryan, I want the string from the checkbox as a value! The label text=that string i want to use...:)